# Using matplotlib slider for PatchCollection and other plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple plots with PatchCollection and generic plots, I wanted to add a slider or key function so that i loops through **frame_1** and **frame_2**. **frame_1 usually goes from 1 to 10** while **frame_2 goes from 1 to 100.** I do not know how to use slider with PatchCollection. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Is there a way to iterate over ax.add_collection() and overwrite the previous plot ?

please see the following code:

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_ylim(max_l,max_r)
    ax.set_xlim(max_l,max_r)

    x1 =       data[int(frame_1)][int(frame_2)][1]
    x2=        data[int(frame_1)][int(frame_2)][2]
    y1 =       data[int(frame_1)][int(frame_2)][3]
    y2 =       data[int(frame_1)][int(frame_2)][4]
    m_left = data[int(frame_1)][int(frame_2)][5]
    m_right= data[int(frame_1)][int(frame_2)][6]

    # Draws a central dotted line with slightly transparent
    lines1, = plt.plot([0, 0], [max_l, max_r], 'grey', alpha=0.25)
    lines2, = plt.plot([max_l, max_r], [0, 0], 'grey', alpha=0.25)

    # Draws a perimeter of a rectangle
    lines3, = plt.plot([(x1),(x1)], [(y1), (y2)],'red', linewidth=2.0)
    lines4, = plt.plot([(x2),(x2)], [(y1), (y2)],'red', linewidth=2.0)
    lines5, = plt.plot([(x1),(x2)],[(y1),(y1)],'red', linewidth=2.0)
    lines6, = plt.plot([(x1),(x2)],[(y2),(y2)],'red', linewidth=2.0)

    # Inserts special rectangles into the figure
    for i in np.arange(len(n)):
        pos = mpatches.Rectangle([max_l, pos_numbers[i]], pos_left[i] , 10, ec="none")
        patches.append(pos)
        pos = mpatches.Rectangle([pos_right[i], pos_numbers[i]],pos_right[i]),10 , ec="none")
        patches.append(pos)

    collection = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.25)
    ax.add_collection(collection)

   # I created two slider for frame_1 and frame_2 but I am struck with the PatchCollection. I do not know what to do with it
   def update(val):
   #   update all the lines (1 to 7)
   #  update special rectangles 
    I even added ax.add_collection(collection) here. it did not help. 

    plt.show()
```

I created a function for special rectangles and called it inside the def update(val). It looks like its creating the fig and overlapping it with the previous figure but its not over-write it. That means it all looks mess when the updating the values.

tried some solution from online then I get the following error

> TypeError: 'PatchCollection' object is not iterable

If there is any other elegant way, please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was so silly of me.

I made a mistake including the patches outside the function. So each time when I called the function it added the previous rectangles to the figure basically increasing the size of patches[]. The following solved the problem

```
def position_r():
    patches = []
    for i in np.arange(len(n)):
        pos = mpatches.Rectangle([max_l, pos_numbers[i]], pos_left[i] , 10, ec="none")
        patches.append(pos)
        pos = mpatches.Rectangle([pos_right[i], pos_numbers[i]],pos_right[i]),10 , ec="none")
        patches.append(pos)

 def remove_collection():
     global collection
     collection.remove

 def update(val):
 #   update all the lines (1 to 7)
 #  update special rectangles

 position_r(updated values)
 remove_collection() # removes the previous rectangles 
 ax.add_collection(collection) # adds the updated rectangles
```